# Wildcard route is not working every route is being redirected

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In angular routing I have added this logic for invalid URL since then every route is being considered as invalid route

```
{path:"login", loadChildren: () => import("./modules/loginpage.module").then(s=> s.loginpageModule),data:{title:'login',showbreadcrumb:'false'}},
{ path: "signup", loadChildren: () => import("./modules/signuppage.module").then(s => s.signuppageModule), data:{title:'signup',showbreadcrumb:'false'}},
{path: "**", pathMatch:"full",loadChildren: () => new Promise( () => {  window.open('/external-link',"_self"); } )}
```

Note: I don't want to add component since I want to redirect to external link

Comment: can you share the other routes you declared? and the route you trying...

Comment: @EliPorush Updated question please check it route I am trying to access is another angular project integrated within same environment

Comment: Which route are you trying to navigate to? Your code looks correct. I don't think you really need "pathMatch: 'full'" on your wildcard route, since it  will match nevertheless each route.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus I'm trying to navigate to external link and even without pathMatch: "full" still getting same issue

Comment: Well, if you try to navigate to external link and every route is matching your wildcard route, it seems to be working as expected, doesn't it? Can you maybe provide a specific example of a route you want to navigate to, where it mistakenly routes to your wildcard route?